# Hide an image on the SD card programmatically on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, image, hide

I tried to hide some images on the SD Card but they aren't hidden.
I tried this code without Success.

Please help me.

===================Code==============

```
Log.e("old path", "" + mTempArry.get(i));//get All file pathe

File fileinDirectory = new File(mTempArry.get(i));

File newfilee = new File(hideImage + fileinDirectory.getName());
Log.e("new path", "" + hideImage + fileinDirectory.getName());

boolean d = fileinDirectory.renameTo(newfilee);

if (d) {
    try {

        getContentResolver()
                .delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='"
                                + fileinDirectory.getPath()
                                + "'", null);
        db.insertImage(fileinDirectory.getName(),
                fileinDirectory.getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    filesmoved = filesmoved + 1;

    publishProgress(filesmoved + "/" + totalFilesToMove);
} else {

    renameFileExtension(mTempArry.get(i), "jpg");

    try {
        copyFile(fileinDirectory, newfilee);
        getContentResolver()
                .delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='"
                                + fileinDirectory.getPath()
                                + "'", null);

        db.insertImage(fileinDirectory.getName(),
                fileinDirectory.getPath());

        // renameFileExtension(mTempArry.get(i), "txt");

        fileinDirectory.delete();

        Log.e("rename", "" + d);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File fileFrom = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"image.jpg");
File fileTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "." + "image.jpg");
fileFrom.renameTo(fileTo);
```

Its basically renaming the file and starting it with a dot(.). Since android has linux kernel, it hides every file that starts with a dot(.).

Make sure you have these permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also note that, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` represent the folder of the image on SDCard.